# laravel localization language switcher

Tags: php, laravel

Im trying to make a language swithcer in my laravel projekt, i follow a tutorials.

First i open my config/app.php and add:

```
'available_locales' => [
    'English' => 'en',
    'Russian' => 'ru',
    'Germany' => 'de',
    'Spain' => 'es',
    'Italy' => 'it',
    'Poland' => 'pl',
    'Portugal' => 'pt',
    'Sweden' => 'sv',
    'Finland' => 'fi',
    'Latvia' => 'lv',
    'Denmark' => 'da',
    'Greece' => 'gr',
    'Netherlands' => 'nl',
    'Estonia' => 'est',
    'Norway' => 'no',
    'France' => 'fr',
    ],
```

and the standard: 'locale' => 'en',

and i create the language file for every language in the resources/lang/

I open my routes/web.php and add to the code:

```
Route::get('/{locale?}', function ($locale = null) {
    if (isset($locale) && in_array($locale, config('app.available_locales'))) {
        app()->setLocale($locale);
    } 
    return view('newindex');
});
```

and in my app/Http/Middleware/Localization.php

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Session::has('locale')) {
            App::setLocale(Session::get('locale'));
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

and in my app/http/Kernel.php web group i add:

```
\App\Http\Middleware\Localization::class,
```

and Changing routes in web.php

```
Route::get('lang/{locale}', function ($locale) {
    app()->setLocale($locale);
    session()->put('locale', $locale);
    return redirect()->back();
});
```

so far so god, the i open the app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php
and add to the code:

```
public function boot()
{
    view()->composer('partials.language_switcher', function ($view) {
        $view->with('current_locale', app()->getLocale());
        $view->with('available_locales', config('app.available_locales'));
    });
}
```

Every thing seems to work great, but when i go to another page like booking i get Page Not Found.
under resources/views i have my booking.blade.php

And in the web.php i add

```
Route::get('/booking-plan', function () {
    return view('booking');
});
```

But it still doesent work, is i missing something.

**UPPDATE:**
My web.php

```
<?php
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| User Authentication Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

Auth::routes();

Route::post('/otp', 'Auth\RegisterController@OTP');

Route::post('/contact/us', 'HomeController@contactus')->name('contact');

Route::get('auth/facebook', 'Auth\SocialLoginController@redirectToFaceBook');
Route::get('auth/facebook/callback', 'Auth\SocialLoginController@handleFacebookCallback');
Route::get('auth/google', 'Auth\SocialLoginController@redirectToGoogle');
Route::get('auth/google/callback', 'Auth\SocialLoginController@handleGoogleCallback');
Route::post('account/kit', 'Auth\SocialLoginController@account_kit')->name('account.kit');
Route::post('/common/socket' , 'SocketController@commonSocket');

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Provider Authentication Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

Route::group(['prefix' => 'provider'], function () {

    Route::get('auth/facebook', 'Auth\SocialLoginController@providerToFaceBook');
    Route::get('auth/google', 'Auth\SocialLoginController@providerToGoogle');

    Route::get('/login', 'ProviderAuth\LoginController@showLoginForm');
    Route::post('/login', 'ProviderAuth\LoginController@login');
    Route::post('/logout', 'ProviderAuth\LoginController@logout');

    Route::get('/register', 'ProviderAuth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm');
    Route::post('/register', 'ProviderAuth\RegisterController@register');

    Route::post('/password/email', 'ProviderAuth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
    Route::post('/password/reset', 'ProviderAuth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
    Route::get('/password/reset', 'ProviderAuth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm');
    Route::get('/password/reset/{token}', 'ProviderAuth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm');


    Route::post('/otp', 'ProviderAuth\RegisterController@OTP');
});

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Admin Authentication Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Route::get('/login', 'AdminAuth\LoginController@showLoginForm');
    Route::post('/login', 'AdminAuth\LoginController@login');
    Route::post('/logout', 'AdminAuth\LoginController@logout');

    Route::post('/password/email', 'AdminAuth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
    Route::post('/password/reset', 'AdminAuth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
    Route::get('/password/reset', 'AdminAuth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm');
    Route::get('/password/reset/{token}', 'AdminAuth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm');
});

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Dispatcher Authentication Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

Route::group(['prefix' => 'dispatcher'], function () {
    Route::get('/login', 'DispatcherAuth\LoginController@showLoginForm');
    Route::post('/login', 'DispatcherAuth\LoginController@login');
    Route::post('/logout', 'DispatcherAuth\LoginController@logout');

    Route::post('/password/email', 'DispatcherAuth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
    Route::post('/password/reset', 'DispatcherAuth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
    Route::get('/password/reset', 'DispatcherAuth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm');
    Route::get('/password/reset/{token}', 'DispatcherAuth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm');
});

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Fleet Authentication Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/


Route::group(['prefix' => 'fleet'], function () {
    Route::get('/login', 'FleetAuth\LoginController@showLoginForm');
    Route::post('/login', 'FleetAuth\LoginController@login');
    Route::post('/logout', 'FleetAuth\LoginController@logout');

    Route::post('/password/email', 'FleetAuth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
    Route::post('/password/reset', 'FleetAuth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
    Route::get('/password/reset', 'FleetAuth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm');
    Route::get('/password/reset/{token}', 'FleetAuth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm');
});

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Account Authentication Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/


Route::group(['prefix' => 'account'], function () {
    Route::get('/login', 'AccountAuth\LoginController@showLoginForm');
    Route::post('/login', 'AccountAuth\LoginController@login');
    Route::post('/logout', 'AccountAuth\LoginController@logout');

    Route::get('/register', 'AccountAuth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm');
    Route::post('/register', 'AccountAuth\RegisterController@register');

    Route::post('/password/email', 'AccountAuth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
    Route::post('/password/reset', 'AccountAuth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
    Route::get('/password/reset', 'AccountAuth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm');
    Route::get('/password/reset/{token}', 'AccountAuth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm');
});

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
Route::get('/{locale?}', function ($locale = null) {
    if (isset($locale) && in_array($locale, config('app.available_locales'))) {
        app()->setLocale($locale);
    } 
    return view('newindex');
});

Route::get('lang/{locale}', function ($locale) {
    app()->setLocale($locale);
    session()->put('locale', $locale);
    return redirect()->back();
});

Route::get('/initsetup', function () {
    return Setting::all();
});

Route::get('/ride', function () {
    return view('ride');
});

Route::get('/about_us', function () {
    return view('aboutus');
});

Route::get('/booking-plan', function () {
    return view('booking');
});

Route::get('/ride', 'Auth\RegisterController@ride');
Route::get('/sendmail', 'SendMailController@index');
Route::post('/sendmail/verify', 'SendMailController@verify')->name('verify');
Route::post('/sendmail/createusers', 'SendMailController@createusers')->name('createusers');
Route::get('/sendmail/form', 'SendMailController@showmailform')->name('showmailform');

Route::get('/drive', function () {
    return view('drive');
});

Route::get('privacy', function () {
    $page = 'page_privacy';
    $title = 'Privacy Policy';
    return view('static', compact('page', 'title'));
});

Route::get('terms', function () {
    $page = 'terms';
    $title = 'Terms and Conditions';
    return view('static', compact('page', 'title'));
});
Route::get('cancellation', function () {
    $page = 'cancel';
    $title = 'Cancellation Rules';
    return view('static', compact('page', 'title'));
});

Route::get('help', function () {
    $page = 'help';
    $title = 'Help';
    return view('static', compact('page', 'title'));
});


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| User Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

Route::get('/dashboard', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('/hour/{id}', 'UserApiController@pricing_logic');

// user profiles
Route::get('/profile', 'HomeController@profile');
Route::get('/edit/profile', 'HomeController@edit_profile');
Route::post('/profile', 'HomeController@update_profile');

// update password
Route::get('/change/password', 'HomeController@change_password');
Route::post('/change/password', 'HomeController@update_password');

// ride
Route::get('/confirm/ride', 'RideController@confirm_ride');
Route::post('/create/ride', 'RideController@create_ride');
Route::post('/cancel/ride', 'RideController@cancel_ride');
Route::get('/onride', 'RideController@onride');
Route::post('/payment', 'PaymentController@payment');
Route::post('/rate', 'RideController@rate');

// status check
Route::get('/status', 'RideController@status');
Route::get('/user/incoming', 'HomeController@incoming');


// trips
Route::get('/trips', 'HomeController@trips');
Route::get('/upcoming/trips', 'HomeController@upcoming_trips');

// wallet
Route::get('/wallet', 'HomeController@wallet');
Route::post('/add/money', 'PaymentController@add_money');

Route::post('/rzp/success', 'PaymentController@rzp_success');

//rzp flow
Route::post('/rzp/flow', 'PaymentController@rzp_flow');

// payment
Route::get('/payment', 'HomeController@payment');

// card
Route::resource('card', 'Resource\CardResource');

// promotions
Route::get('/promotions', 'HomeController@promotions_index')->name('promocodes.index');
Route::post('/promotions', 'HomeController@promotions_store')->name('promocodes.store');

Route::post('/fare' , 'UserApiController@fare');
```

my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: share your complete route file. i.e `web.php`

Comment: move the route ``Route::get('/{locale?}'`` at the end or else every other static routes will be handled by this due to dynamic URL parameter!!

Comment: as said ... `{locale?}` is a wildcard and will catch any path with only that 1 segment, that needs to be moved

Comment: I still get Page Not Found. when i go to one page true localhost, but when i go php artisan serve it works.

Comment: are you using apache, sounds like you don't have url rewriting enabled correctly potentially

Comment: url rewriting is enable, update in main topic my .htaccess